# Sinch API JS, instant messaging. User creation is disabled for this application

Tags: sinch

I'm trying to create user for start instant messaging

```
$('button#register').on('click', function(event){

   event.preventDefault();
   $('button#register').attr('disabled', true);
   clearError();

   var signUpObj = {};
   signUpObj.username = $('input#username').val();
   signUpObj.password = $('input#password').val();

   sinchClient.newUser(signUpObj, function(ticket) {

       sinchClient.start(ticket, function() {
           global_username = signUpObj.username;

           localStorage[sessionName] = JSON.stringify(sinchClient.getSession());
       }).fail(handleError);
   }).fail(handleError);
})
```

But I'm receiving error message

```
errorCode: 40303
message: User creation is disabled for this application
```

So, what I should done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dashboard of you app (sinch.com/dashboard), enable js auth

Comment: I already did that but i get the same error code. Any other sugestion? I literally only opened up the sample.html file or should I be doing anything else?